# Is there any tool to access the Non Relational Database like IMS other than Mainframe?

Tags: mainframe, non-relational-database, dbvisualizer

I am looking for a tool to connect to Non relational Database IMS. Is there any tool available? Similar to DBVisualizer for Relational Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a free IBM tool that allows you to visualize the database structure from DBD/PSB source:

http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/imsentesuitexpl/

Here are instructions on how to use it for your purpose (I think):

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ims.explorer21.doc%2Fwb_qt_editingfields.htm

You can see if it is suitable for you by using the examples that are provided with the download:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ims.explorer22.doc%2Fwb_samplefordatabasevisualization.htm

---

Comment: Thank you Rafraf for the solution